# How to logout via URL in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have to logout a user from a WordPress site where the top bar is disabled and no logout option is available at any page.

Is there a general link to logout from WordPress?

Answer (score 44):

> /wp-login.php?action=logout

Is what was used in the past.

References:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/

Comment: This link will prompt you to confirm that you want to logout, since the link is missing nonce.

Comment: Helpful if you've marked a user as having no role to deactivate them, then try to log in as them to test it's worked. Login is allowed, but access to wp-admin is denied.

Comment: Helpful indeed, I found myself locked out from a Multisite Super Admin. It would be a matter of clearing cookies but ackward nonetheless

Answer (score 13):

I think the better method is to get the nonce and redirect to the home page:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url()); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [wp_loginout()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout) function that displays the a logout link if user is logged in or login link if it is not.

To add this link to the WordPress menu, check [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-a-loginlogout-link-to-your-wordpress-menu/) article. Basically, just add the following code to *functions.php*:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below url:

`domian-name.com/wp-login.php?action=logout`

Change `domain-name.com` with your website's domain name.

After hitting this URL, you will be asked to confirm. That's it.